# Reinstall windows with Ubuntu alongside

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-tweak

I have a windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed. For quite sometime now, I am facing problems in Windows OS. 
So I wanted to change few things. I have two options:

1. I can reinstall the windows again but I want to keep the Ubuntu installed. It is on separate partition.
2. or I can remove Window and install Ubuntu fully. Here also I want to keep the softwares which are already installed in Ubuntu.

So my question is whether or not it is possible do that. My requirement is that during the process Ubuntu remains unaffected. I have some very important softwares installed in Ubuntu.

EDIT: I want to know if it is the the hardware problem or the software problem because I have ubuntu installed on the same hard drive and it has never freezed.

Comment: Is not clear what you're asking. To clarify, are you asking how to remove Windows and give Ubuntu all of your disk space, or are you asking how to reinstall Windows 7 without affecting Ubuntu?

Comment: I am asking whether or not it is possible to fix the problem using either of the route of points 1 and 2. Just that I don't want to alter the existing set up of Ubuntu. I hope it clarify the question. If not I can explain in more detail.

Comment: Ah, OK. That is more clear. What's missing now is what your problem with Windows specifically is. All you've said is "I am facing problems in Windows OS". You've suggested some solutions, which is great. We just need to know what the problem is to suggest solutions.

Comment: Ok, so here's the problem. When I use Windows, my system freezes. It happens randomly. It has nothing to do with the duration of use. It can freeze while loading, or into use. So I was hoping reinstalling could do the trick.

Comment: OK. Reinstalling might help. If that's what you decide to do, @Yo Yo Saty Singh gave a good answer for that. Before taking such drastic measures, though, I would consult the SuperUser StackExchange to see if you can fix the freezing without a total reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramvir,

If you have a working version of windows along with Ubuntu. Log into windows and then insert a CD drive and use GUI options to reinstall windows OS.

Probably, it will stop recognizing the Ubuntu OS.

Simple way to fix this issue is, you have boot the system with alternate CD of Ubuntu and install Boot-Repair Tool.

[Follow this link for Boot-Repair Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Once you are done with the these steps, just restart system and you will get both OS running alongside.

Comment: +1 for giving the point that re-installing windows will over write **grub** with Windows **MBR** and suggesting using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Windows does not affect your Ubuntu partition. The only problem that it can cause is boot problems. So, update GRUB after installing Windows.

The *.deb files of installed packages are located in var/cache/apt/archives.
So if you want to reinstall the same verion of Ubuntu, you can reserve them in another disk.

Note: the packages in var/cache/apt/archives. will be deleted after some time or using `apt-get autoclean`. Anyway there might be located important installations.